# an issue with client tampering causing the server to restart

Tags: node.js, sockets, security, server, socket.io

**I wrote some code in my chat site
Automatic reconnection when connection is lost
The codes work well, but there is a problem, which is that the socket is used as a loophole in the console**

```
socket.emit("rc", {
                token: token,
                n: lk
            });
```

****`Which causes the server to restart by the client`

---

**I tried defining a typeof
The codes stopped working
What can I do**

## *The code is complete*

````
socket.on("rc",function(data){
        UsersRepo.getByToken(data['token']).then(function(login){
        if(login){
        const islog = online.findIndex((v) => v.lid == login.lid)
        if(islog != -1){
        if(UserInfo[online[islog].id]){
        UserInfo[online[islog].id].id = socket.id;
        };
        UserInfo[socket.id] = UserInfo[online[islog].id];
        io.emit("msg", { cmd: "u-", data: online[islog].id });
        io.emit("msg", { cmd: "ur", data: [online[islog].id, null] });
        delete UserInfo[online[islog].id];
        online[islog].id = socket.id;
        setTimeout(function(){
        io.emit("msg", { cmd: "u+", data: online[islog] });
        io.emit("msg", { cmd: "ulist", data: online });
        setTimeout(function(){
        socket.join(online[islog].roomid);
        if(online[islog]){
        io.emit("msg", { cmd: "ur", data: [socket.id, online[islog].roomid] });
        };
        },500);```


I'm still trying to fix this code

With the help of some experts
````